# Why does absolute convergence of a series imply the function is analytic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I keep reading that if a series representing a function is absolutely convergent, then the function is analytic.

**Question: Why is this?** I can't find an answer in textbooks like Apostol, Stopple, nor online.

The common example is the Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$ where the following series is valid for $\Re(s)>1$.

$$ \zeta(s) = \sum\frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \ldots $$

Comment: This depends  on what kind of series we are talking about and on what kind of sets is the convergence considered; for power series it follows from definition more or less on open sets but not on boundary; for dirichlet  series it follows from various results but same on open half plane not on boundary; for Fourier series on the other hand absol convergence  is very weak implying fairly little; what implies analyticity is uniform convergence  on compact subsets of open sets of series of analytic  functions and absolute convergence  implies that in those common situations above

Comment: thanks @Conrad for the pointers. I will have to read about uniform convergence implying analyticity (self-teaching maths). I had previously understood analyticity from the calculus perspective requiring a function to be (infinitely) complex differentiable - and therefore having a power series expansion. I realise this isn't a Dirichlet series.